# Solving limits without L'Hôpital

Tags: limits, trigonometry

We have the following limits:

$\lim_\limits{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{1- \tan^2 x}{\cos 2x}$ and $\lim_\limits{\theta \to 1} = \dfrac{\theta -1 + \sin(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta ^2 -1}$

Using L'Hôpital I obtained that the second limit is $\theta = \dfrac{3}{2}$. For the first limit I was able to rewrite it to $\lim_\limits{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} (1-\tan^2(x))\sec(2x)$, but I don't really know what to do with that.

Is there a way to make these limits simpler using trigonometry instead of L'Hôpital's rule (or in the case of the first limit, instead of nothing which is what I have now)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first limit, some elementary trigonometry (a duplication formula) will do:
$$\frac{1-\tan^2x}{cos 2x}=\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x\cos 2x}=\frac{\cos2x}{\cos^2x\cos 2x}=\frac1{\cos^2x}\xrightarrow[x\to\scriptstyle\frac\pi4]{}2.$$

For the second limit, use asymptotic analysis:
$$\frac{\theta -1 + \sin(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta ^2 -1}=\frac{\theta -1 +\theta ^2 -1+ o(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta ^2 -1}=\frac1{\theta+1}+1+o(1)\xrightarrow[\theta\to1]{}\frac12+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

use the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$
$$ \dfrac{\theta -1 + \sin(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta ^2 -1}=\frac{\theta-1}{\theta^2-1}+\frac{\sin(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\theta+1}+\frac{\sin(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta^2-1}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}(\frac{1}{\theta+1}+\frac{\sin(\theta ^2 -1)}{\theta^2-1})=1/2+1=3/2$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, note that $\cos 2x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$, while the top is $\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)$.